# An error occurred while using std::function ( error C2064: c++ term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments)

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, std-function, unreal-engine5

The following error occurred while developing using C++. What could be the cause?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images, post text. But in any case it's pretty clear that your function takes one argument, not zero. So that is the cause of the error.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_CurrentStatus`, `_StatusChangeCallBack`, `_InputStatus`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your parameter is `std::function<void(ARTSPlayerController&)>`which takes one argument. Then you try to call your callback `_StatusChangeCallback()` which should take one argument, but you didn't pass any.